# a loop won't break in C

Tags: c, loops

I have been delving into C and rather using `scanf()` I wanna try to build my own function to get an entire line. I wrote this function that returns a line to be compared in my main function, except it won't break out of the loop to print my result.

I don't know if it's the actual function or just how I implemented it in `main()`.

Here's the code:

```
main() {
    int len;
    int max = 0; //Largest line so far..
    char linetemp[MAXLINE]; 
    char linemax[MAXLINE];
    while((len = getLine(linetemp,MAXLINE))> 0){
        if(len>max){
            max = len;
            cpy(linemax,linetemp);
        }
    }   
    if(max>0) {  //If their was even a line
        printf("Longest Line:\n %s \n", linemax);
    } else {
        printf("No lines found!");
    }
}

int getLine(char l[], int lim) {
    int c, i;
    for(i=0; i< lim - 1 && (c=getchar())!= '\n' && c != EOF ;++i)
        l[i]= c;
    if(c =='\n') {
        l[i]= c;
        ++i;
    }
    l[i]= '\0';
    return i;
}
```

Comment: You will not break out of the loop until EOF is reached. Your code looks OK to me. You haven't posted the implementation of `cpy`. Could that be a source of your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `while` loop in `main` only ends if the length returned is zero, but it never can be unless the only character read is `EOF`.  If someone just presses Enter, it will add the newline and increment the size, so 1 is returned.

Perhaps you want to remove the special case handling of `if(c=='\n')` and let it return an empty string if someone presses enter without other text.

Comment: Well I tried that but to no avail. It just continues to listen for char. Just contains blank. BUT see that now so I'm thinking to adjust it, to then change the while loop in main!Thanks!